# Firebase Database query: test for existence of a given value without being able to list all values

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a Firebase Database that looks like this.

```
root
  devices
    00EB4A1
    0008634
  devices_unowned
    00056F3
    000A689
```

A single device is only ever listed under `devices` or `devices_unowned`, never both. I need a secure way to allow an unowned device to become owned, without exposing the list of unowned devices.

A user of my mobile app may stumble upon a device that is currently unowned. I need them to be able to execute a query such as "`root/devices_unowned/000A689 exists, yes or no?`" but NOT to be able to execute one such as "`list all the devices at /root/devices_unowned`".

Is this possible?

Comment: So that means that you would have to move the device to another path when it becomes owned? I would advise against that. What if there are pending writes that will modify the old path instead of the new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems very feasible to me:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "devices": {
      "$deviceid": {
        ".read": true
      }
    },
    "devices_unowned": {
      "$deviceid": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules every user can read each specific device, but no user (except those with administrative permissions) can read a list of all devices.